# ORACLE: Insert into table with join on view+table and sum() functions (GROUP BY ERROR)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions, insert-into

I am trying to insert Data from a View (which has its source in a different Database and is connected via DB-link) and a Table of accounts into a existing Table. I don´t know how much information you need to solve this Problem becouse I don´t know its source so I will write everything that could be relevant.

The new Table will have a auto-generated ID as its primary key and a foreigner key which is the ID of the Account Table. Lets name it Targettable.

The account table is recursiv for example: aca, acb are childs of ac and ac is a child of a.

In the View the accountnames are saved like this: a/ac/aca. Also every account can be named multiple times becouse the accounts can be from different types (which are not relevant for the Targettable)

The *Select* command works perfectly fine and looks like this:

```
Select accounts.id, sum(value1), sum(value2), sum(value3), startdate, enddate
from dataview 
inner join accounts on accounts.name = Substr(view.id, -1, 1) /* takes the lowest hierarchical level */
and accounts.superior = (select id from accounts where name = substr(view.id,-3,2)) /* takes the superier hierachical level */
group by accounts.id, startdate, enddate;
```

Now i want to do this:

```
Insert into Targettable (accountid, netto, brutto, somevalue, startdate, enddate, valid)
 Select accounts.id, sum(value1), sum(value2), sum(value3), startdate, enddate, 'Y'
 from dataview 
 inner join accounts 
 on accounts.name = Substr(view.id, -1, 1) /* takes the lowest hierarchical level */
 and accounts.superior = (select id from accounts where name = substr(view.id,-3,2) /* takes the superier hierachical level */
 group by accounts.id, startdate, enddate
 ;
```

If i try to do this i get a ORA-00979 Error: "not a GROUP BY expression" in row 1 and column 1 which helps me a lot.

**EDIT:**
Can this be a problem of Databaselink somehow? Becouse of Transactions or something?

Comment: Where is the closing bracket for this subquery: (select id from accounts where name = substr(view.id,-3,2) ? And I don't see alias 'view' declared anywhere. Are you sure, this query works?

Comment: If the `select` works, then it should work with `insert`.

Comment: @Mikhail sorry i forgot the closing bracket in my question but thats not the error and yeah the query works ... and it also shows me the exact data i want i also tried it with alias but it doesnt matter if i use one or not

Answer (score 0):

Setting the missing closing bracket pointed by Mikhail aside, this might be a bug that have already been encountered [in the Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/message/13227544#13227544). Following the advise given there, you should try with:

```
Insert into Targettable (accountid, netto, brutto, somevalue, startdate, enddate, valid)
with temp as (
 Select accounts.id as id, sum(value1) as value1, sum(value2) as value2, sum(value3) as value3, startdate, enddate, 'Y' as valid
 from dataview inner join accounts 
 on accounts.name = Substr(view.id, -1, 1) /* takes the lowest hierarchical level */
 and accounts.superior = (select id from accounts where name = substr(view.id,-3,2)) /* takes the superier hierachical level */
 group by accounts.id, startdate, enddate
 )
 select id, value1, value2, value3, startdate, enddate, valid
 from temp
```

Comment: already tried something like this (and to be sure your suggestion too) sadly it does not help anything